# Difference between L78xx and L78xxC

Tags: voltage-regulator, components, temperature

Does anyone know what is the difference between L78XX with L78XXC? Is the C meaning capacitor?

Comment: Difficult to answer unless you give a datasheet. For ST it means a different temperature grade and other things, but maybe it doesn't for your manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

L78xxC is the version rated for the commercial operating temperature range, which can only go as low as 0 C. See [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/41/4f/b3/b0/12/d4/47/88/CD00000444.pdf/files/CD00000444.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000444.pdf).

The non-C version, L78xx, can go as low as -55 C and uses the huge metallic TO-3 can package. You'll probably see it in space/military/industrial applications... if you can find any that is not already obsolete (this is a very old part/package).

From an older ST [datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/246063/STMICROELECTRONICS/L7805C.html):

[image]

[image]